# What does zero-mean noise mean?

Tags: noise, image-processing

I don't know where to start from. and this question might be very silly,

I have found such as comment from someone at [Poisson noise and curve fitting - denoise first?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15967/poisson-noise-and-curve-fitting-denoise-first),

"I think if your noise is zero-mean it doesn't matter, if not it does (you should de-noise first). I'm not entirely sure though so I won't put it in an answer yet."

Q1. Actually, I want to know what does zero-mean noise mean? and what does it not matter means?

Q2. Why we presume that the noise in Gaussian filter have sigma 1 and mean 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an easy concept but a sometimes it is hard to express it compactly.
The difficulty arises because of additional concepts to be known for any formal description.

As you may know, mathematical analysis of noise variables and signals are handled via the tools of probability theory, in particular by the stochastic (random) processes.

The usual progress is such that first properties of random variables are described and then properties of random signals are derived based on it.

The mean for a random variable, X, is defined to be its Expected Value E(X) and computed based on its Probability Density Function $f_X(x)$ such as $\mu_X = \int {xf_X(x) dx}$ with the limits from minus to plus infinity for a continuous random variable.

So a zero mean random variable is that one for which the above integral is zero. (for a discrete random variable the integral is replaced by a sum and pdf is replaced by a pmf). This is also called as the average value.

Random signals are considered to be made up of an infinite set of random variables each making a single value at a single instance of observation of the instance being created. Hence there is the concept of ensemble and time averages.

Now coming to random signals X(t) (noise) expected value of a random signal is also expressed as E(X(t)) which for a Stationary (or at east Weakly Stationary up to second order) Process is a fixed value.

Your answer is that a zero mean noise is that one for which E(X(t)) is zero for all t.

However above is a theoretical description of Mean. In practice to compute mean and other theoretical parameters, you will refer to statistical computation which deal with practically observed data and computations based on that.

The key which connects statistically made (practical) computations to theoretical computations is the Ergodicity Theorem which states that for an ergodic random process theoretical computations are equal to statistical ones.

Comment: Thank yo so much Sir, Briefly, Do you want to say what if we get all noise signals then the sum of noise signal is zero?  If so, I am correct,  this is only in Gaussian noise model? or Poisson noise model?

Comment: @gmotree Practically (due to the Ergodicity Theorem) the sum of the samples (or subsequently the average) will be very close to zero for a zero mean random signal whatsoever its model is.

Comment: No, Sir. I'm not down voter.

Comment: BTW, I have accepted your answer Thank you so much. Then I have one more question.  What does std=1 noise mean? why typically the noise model have mean=0(you have already explained) std=1?

Comment: @gmtree I saw, thanks ;) I assume  std = standart deviation. It is the square root of Variance, which is = $E( (X-E(X))^2)$

Comment: I have already know the meaning of std what std is standard deviation. But I want to know why typically the noise model have std=1? what does std=1 mean at noise model? if you want to make me another question then plz let me know. i'll make another question.

Comment: @gmtree if you specifically refer to a gaussian noise, then the most standard gausian is defined to have a mean of zero and sdt of 1. which is described as N(0,1) standard normal. Its certain properties are tabulated for computations of other gaussians which have nonzero mean and nonunity standard deviations.

Comment: Sir, if I refer to Poisson noise then how does std and mean have mean?

Comment: @gmtree regardless of the type being gaussian, uniform, poisson, gamma, exponential, bernoulli, binomial etc... mean and std deviations have the same meaning and computations. However for a gaussian type, it is common to express its mean and std deviation parameters to define it.

Comment: i think Bulent S. that the questin refered to poisson noise and relation to gaussian normalised noise and you have did explained wikipedia way mean and stantart deviation definition.

Comment: @Black Yasmin: Where in the Question the word "Poisson" passes ? Do you mean in the Comments ???

Comment: @BlackYasmin Who is  Bulent S ? I don't know what's your point.

Comment: @gmotree There is also a physical and intuitive explanation for AWGN having zero mean. The noise is caused by thermically excited electrons moving in a resistor; each contributes a little bit of noise current (and voltage). Each electron's behavior is independent of the others'. Since there are millions of them, it's likely that, on average, for each one contributing a positive voltage, there will be another contributing an equal and negative voltage. That's why thermal noise has zero mean.

Comment: @MBaz I just have interesting for image noise.

Comment: @Fat32 Sir but, especially, in the noise of image, there is no under 0 value. The interval of image signal is normally 0~255, so I can't think the mean  go to zero. If noise signal does not have zero mean, It is different what the gaussian mean =0 and std=1. Whould you please let me know regarding this?

Comment: @gmtree for an image intensity which is always non-negative, you can simply modify your added N(0,1) standard gaussian noise in 3 steps: 1-scale it so that your noise has whatever std you wish. 2-add whatever proper mean you need such as 128. 3-clip the noise for below zero and above 255 samples. This is simple bt It will help you get what you need at least initially.

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks Sir let me know about 3 steps. But I can't catch the idea quite a bit. So would you help me with example?

Comment: @gmtree which step do you have problem with ?

Comment: @Fat32 Sir, especially, 2 and 3. How can I add and clip? Can you illustrate it?

Comment: If the question has already been given a tick, there should be no need for further discussion. As it is, the system is warning me that there are too many comments here.  Please take any extended discussion to chat!

Comment: @Peter K. sometimes it happens..! So as can be seen besides the comments have diverged from the original question... gmtree might better post new ones for any further investigation ;)

Comment: @Fat32 : Agreed! New question time.  I had the option of just deleting all the comments, but thought a gentle reminder might be better. :-)